# validate dropdown field in asp.net mvc 3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

code is:

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "RegisterForm" }))
{

`@Html.DropDownList("StateId", new SelectList(Model.States, "StateId", "StateName"), 
"--Select an option--", new { @tabindex = "11" })`

}

i need required field validation for dropdown

Comment: Validate it how? Can you provide some more detail?

Comment: @yogee, show more code. What's the problem, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Data Annotations in your model to mark the property as required?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a State")]
```

Are you exposing the `StateId` as a part of the Model? If so that's where you should set the Required Attribute, like so:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a State")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
```